# CSS walking animation in wordpress header

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I found css animation codes and changed to handle mouse clicks. It works in localhost and codepen but not in wordpress header.

```
var index = 0;
var event = new Event('stopEvent');

var sprite = document.querySelector('.sprite'),
    key = {left: false, right: false},
    trans = 0,
    property = getTransformProperty(sprite);

function getTransformProperty(element) {
    var properties = [
        'transform',
        'WebkitTransform',
        'msTransform',
        'MozTransform',
        'OTransform'
    ];
    var p;
    while (p = properties.shift()) {
        if (typeof element.style[p] != 'undefined') {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function translate() {
    sprite.style[property] = 'translateX(' + trans + 'px)';
}
```

http://codepen.io/yusufunlu/pen/yOJXaG
This is   [My Wordpress Web site](http://www.unlu.co/)
I used chrome debugger to inspect my web site. It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" any idea to solve that ?

Comment: While p= properties.shift ? it should be == or === ?

Comment: Thank you for warn. I have changed but it is still same.